# Allowing non root users to manage systemd service is not working

Tags: linux, systemd, sudo

I wanted to allow specific non root users to start/stop certain systemd services in CentOS7. But there has been no luck on the steps that I have tried so far. Here is what I have tried.

I have added the below details in sudoers file where testsudo is a user group and couple of users have been added to that group.

```
## Manage specific systemd services
Cmnd_Alias SYSTEMD = /bin/systemctl start httpd, /bin/systemctl stop httpd, /bin/systemctl restart httpd

## Allows nfam group to run init-system commands using the SYSTEMD command alias
%testsudo ALL=NOPASSWD: SYSTEMD
```

**Details of the group and added users:**

```
# cat /etc/group | grep testsudo
testsudo:x:1009:userone,usertwo,userthree
```

Now if I try to start the service using any one of the user (who is a part of testsudo group), I get an authentication required message.

```
[userone@msgdroid ~]$ systemctl start httpd
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  admin
 2.  priya
 3.  sekar
 4.  gokul
 5.  ravi
 6.  murali
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-6):
```

## Update1:

I have also used **sudo** infront of the command, but it doesn't work even.

```
$ sudo systemctl start httpd
[sudo] password for userone:
Sorry, user userone is not allowed to execute '/bin/systemctl start httpd' as root on webapp.
```

## Update2:

- Just a correction, the server can only be accessed via SSH Keys and not via password. Will that be an issue?

Comment: You edited sudoers but didn't invoke `sudo`; do you want to use sudoers?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, is there any other alternate approach without using sudoers?

Comment: Is testsudo a member of the sudo group? If not then that won't work as printed. Because userone may be in testsudo but if testsudo is not in sudo the resultis the same.

Comment: I tested your configuration on a Debian server and it works. I suggest you to double check the syntax of the commands you entered in `sudoers` file (did you use `visudo` to do this ?).  Check the spaces are spaces (and not alt-space e.g.), eventually rewrite it from zero.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see the output from `sudo -l` as userone on that system.  Access via keys is no problem, as it appears that you know the password for the userone user.

Comment: @MichaelProkopec testsudo is a group (preceded with a %).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try this:

```
sudo systemctl start httpd
```

You have to log out then log in again after you modified you sudoers file (you may not be able to use `sudo` until you do this).

You can also edit and replace the following:

```
%testsudo ALL=NOPASSWD: SYSTEMD
```

with

```
%testsudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: SYSTEMD
```

Comment: Tried adding sudo but it doesn't help. Updated the question.

Comment: Did you log out from `userone` then log in again ?

Comment: Yes I have logged out and logged in back.

Comment: I edited my answer, see if it works

Comment: Hi anonymous downvoter, can you explain ?

Comment: That ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: SYSTEMD, is not what you want to do.

Comment: @MichaelProkopec adding `testsudo` to `sudo` group is not what you want to do neither, but I didn't downvote. Actually, adding `(root)` allows to execute the command as `root`. As OP had the `Sorry, user userone is not allowed to execute '/bin/systemctl start httpd' as root on webapp.` message, I proposed this. Do you have a better suggestion ?

Comment: @MichaelProkopec From `sudoers` manpage it seems it is an `=`'s option allowing to run command as a specific user:

*`WEBMASTERS      www = (www) ALL, (root) /usr/bin/su www`

     On the host www, any user in the WEBMASTERS User_Alias (will, wendy, and wim), may run any command as user www (which owns the web pages) or simply su(1) to www.*

Did you read that ?

Comment: `help != judge`. Another thing: a file can be owner by root. But a user, I don't think so...

Comment: If it's a user that is a child "launched by" root, it is thus owned by root. That is why launching programs as root is dangerous the children of that process can then do things they otherwise would not be able to.

Comment: `%testsudo ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: SYSTEMD` translated to English: members of group "testsudo" on ALL hosts using this sudoers file are allowed to execute as root, without being asked for a password, any commands defined earlier on a `CmndAlias SYSTEMD` line.

Comment: Yes but if testsudo is not an actual user then nothing will happen!

Comment: The percent sign before the word `testsudo` means it is a **group** not an user. And the original poster says that the users that need to run the commands have already been added to the `testsudo` group.

Comment: Then groups | testsudo should return the users in that group.

Comment: No you don't have to logout after modifying `/etc/sudoers`, it is re-read every time `sudo` is run. However it is one way to become a member of the new group that you added (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

If using `sudoers`, then you need to use `sudo` but you can hide its use in a script or alias.

I am wondering if the problem is that your users are not yet in the group. Adding a user to a new group, only writes to a file (`/etc/groups`). To activate it you need to start a new process, with the new group. There are two easy ways to do this: 1 logout and back in again; run `newgrp groupname`. This will start a new shell over the current one. It will be added to the new group, if and only if you are a member of the group (according to the file `/etc/groups`).